# Getting an error trying to apply circle overlay in swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode8, mkoverlay, clcircularregion, mkcircle

i encounter an error :

Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MKCircle' with an argument list of type '(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D,radius: int,identifier: String)'

```
    let region = CLCircularRegion(coder: MKCircle(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.destLat!, self.destLong!), radius: 100, identifier: destinationAddress))
    self.locationManager .startMonitoring(for: region)
```

Below is my ovelay method

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

   if overlay is MKCircle {
        let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
        circleRenderer.strokeColor = .purple
        circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        return circleRenderer
    }

    let myLineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: myRoute.polyline)
    myLineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    myLineRenderer.lineWidth = 3
    return myLineRenderer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do, but your declaration of `region` is wrong.
This is the right version:

```
let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.destLat!, self.destLong!), radius: 100, identifier: destinationAddress)
```

Comment: i wanted to apply the circular overlay on that location, how do i do that?